# Display suite removing class id

Tags: theming, display-suite

I split 2 columns my contetnt node with Display Suite and add custom class to the columns. (with Bootsrap responsive class col-sm-3) But display suite still render column with old style: group-left and group right. How can i remove old style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classes are only added to the existing ones, they don't replace them. If you want to remove the old styling, you can create a new layout and either add different default classes, or no classes at all.

[Adding custom layouts to your theme (Display Suite)](https://drupal.org/node/1098068)

You also might want to consider using [Display Suite Bootstrap Layouts](https://drupal.org/project/ds_bootstrap_layouts). Bootstrap 3.0 layouts are still in dev, but it's worth taking a look.